# Nginx Load Balancer High availability running in Docker

Tags: linux, docker, nginx, load-balancing, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am running, nginx load balancer container for my backend web server,

Since I have only one container running as nginx load balancer, In  case of  container die/crash, clients cannot reach webservers,

Below is the nginx.conf

```
events {}
http {
  upstream backend {
      server 1.18.0.2;
      server 1.18.0.3;
   }

   # This server accepts all traffic to port 80 and passes it to the upstream.
   # Notice that the upstream name and the proxy_pass need to match.

   server {
      listen 80;

      location / {
          proxy_pass http://backend;
      }
   }
}
```

Below is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

I am running nginx container like below

```
docker run -d -it -p 8082:80 nginx-ls
```

I am accessing above server with http://serve-ip:8082

Container may crash or die any time, in that case my application is not reachable, So I tried to run another container like below and I am getting below error since I am using same port and it is oblivious we cannot repurpose same port in same host.

```
docker run -d -it -p 8082:80 nginx-ls

06a20239bd303fab2bbe161255fadffd5b468098424d652d1292974b1bcc71f8
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint 
suspicious_darwin (58eeb43d88510e4f67f618aaa2ba06ceaaa44db3ccfb0f7335a739206e12a366): Bind for 
0.0.0.0:8082 failed: port is already allocated.
```

So I ran in different port, It works fine

```
 docker run -d -it -p 8083:80 nginx-ls
```

But How do we tell/configure clients use port 8083 container when container 8082 is down

or is there any other best method to achieve nginx load balancer with high availability?

Note: For some reasons, I cannot use docker-compose

Comment: just Restart Docker it'll be solved

Comment: it will affect other containers, but yes i can develop sort of liveness probe and restart particular Docker container